# C# Web Service WebMethod(enableSession: true) per user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, asmx

I have some web services in my application, with the following:

```
[WebMethod(enableSession: true, CacheDuration = 120)]
```

My trouble is, the output is cached across all sessions which isn't want I was expecting... I was thinking that the cache would be per session if `enableSession` is `true`.

Is there anyway to enable caching (for performance) per session? Or a means to say to the browser to cache the response for "x" seconds?